# Angular Bootstrap navbar not working in play framework

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, playframework, responsive-design, playframework-2.0

I have some code using Angular UI Bootstrap that has a navbar that should turn into a collapsable when viewed on a device with a small screen, however if I'm running this locally in my Play! app this doesnt happen and it just renders as a normal page (zoomed out and small) If I use my browser and make it small it behaves as expected.

The really strange thing is that I put the exact html that Play generates into plunkr and when I go to view it on my phone on plunker, it does shrink as expected..

Is there any setting in Play I need to toggle to make it compatible with small screens?

For reference here is the Plunkr and the HTML, http://plnkr.co/edit/wy67CeGUSSV0edTFbZft

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-controller="NavbarController">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="isNavbarCollapse = !isNavbarCollapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="isNavbarCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <script>
            angular.module('myApp', [
                'ui.bootstrap'
            ]).controller('NavbarController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.isNavbarCollapse = true;
            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this meta tag on the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

And then check that your server serves the `bootstrap.js` file as expected. I don't know how it works with Play, but maybe something like exporting the assets to the public directory.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. And that line is in the bootstrap getting started page... How did I miss that!!!